# Cannot build jquery dform from pased string from controller

Tags: javascript, forms, model-view-controller, jqgrid

I want use dForm in my MVC app.
When I try to build form from following json string it's ok.

```
 var formdata = {
        'action': 'index.html',
        'method': 'get',
        'elements':
                [
                 {
                  "type":"select",
                  "name":"Name",
                  "caption":"Name",
                  "options":"first":{"html":"first","class":"active"},
                            "second":{"html":"second","class":"active"},
                  "selected":null
                 } 
               ]
  };
```

but when I use generated part for elements like:

```
 var elements = {
                "action": "index.html",
                "method": "get",
                "elements":
                        [
                             $('#jqgrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'userData')
                        ]
            };
            $('#myform').buildForm(elements);
```

I get following error from dform:

```
    uncaught exception: No element type given! Must always exist.
```

But I am sure that "elements" tag is the same as I posted in first example.

I have found that in firebug I can see the getted string userData for jqGrid in following format for ex.:

```
"userdata":"{\"type\":\"select\",\"name\":\"Name\",\"caption\":\"Name\",\"options\":{\"first\":\"first\" .....
```

I generate userData from JObject.
Maybe there is the problem. I have tried to replace the escaping character '\' but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

That format doesn't look right. It is probably trying to convert

```
{ "userdata" : "JSON String" }
```

From what I can tell you probably have to do:

```
JSON.parse($('#jqgrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'userData').userdata);
```

If that doesn't do it, check out the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dform?pli=1), it is probably easier to help you there.

Comment: Thank for reply. Your code gives me following error: JSON.parse: unexpected character